# Rules of thumb for PERMANOVA

Tags: multivariate-analysis, assumptions, permutation-test

I'm currently assessing the best option for looking at some community composition data, and determining how they differ among locations. Ultimately, as I'm simply looking to see if there is a difference depending on site (4 level factor), I was looking at Permanovas. Does anybody have any good references which explains the assumptions, such as maximum number of response variables (e.g. how large can the species composition be)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are no limits in the number of variables (species) because the analysis is based on similarities among samples. However, you must be clear about your design, hypothesis and which index you will use (e.g. Bray-Cusrtis, Sorensen, Jaccard, etc). Read the papers of Anderson (2001) and Anderson and Walsh (2013) for details.

Comment: [Anderson 2001](http://entocert.net/PDF/MUVE/6_NewMethod_MANOVA1_2.pdf); [Anderson & Walsh 2013](http://izt.ciens.ucv.ve/ecologia/Archivos/ECO_POB%202013/ECOPO2_2013/Anderson%20y%20Walsh%202013.pdf)